# add more field using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 input fields 1 for image and 1 for video.
I want to add more fields when +Add More button is pressed.
Here is the code

```
<div class="row p-20 partPending">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<x-forms.file allowedFileExtensions="png jpg jpeg" class="mr-0 mr-lg-2 mr-md-2" :fieldLabel="__('app.partImage')" fieldName="part_image"
                            fieldId="part_image" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<x-forms.file allowedFileExtensions=" mp4 avi " allowedFileSize=" 1mb" class="mr-0 mr-lg-2 mr-md-2" :fieldLabel="__('app.partVideo')" fieldName="part_video"
                            fieldId="part_video" />
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row px-lg-4 px-md-4 px-3 pb-3 pt-0 mb-3  mt-2">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <a class="f-15 f-w-500" href="javascript:;" id="add-more"><i
 class="icons icon-plus font-weight-bold mr-1"></i>@lang('app.addMore')</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

```
$("body").on("click",".add-more",function(){ 
var html = $(".partPending").first().clone();
$(html).find(".change").html("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
$(".partPending").last().after(html);
});
 $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".partPending").remove();    
});
```

How can i get the desired result. Please help

Comment: What's your question about the given code? Anything not working with it? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

your issue is about wrong CSS selector :

```
$("body").on("click",".add-more",function(){
```

should be :

```
$("body").on("click","#add-more",function(){
```

ALSO your codes will correctly adds your desired element, but the element contents is nothing so you cannot view it .
you can get some style to the element for view it :

```
.partPending {
   display:block;
   background:yellow;
   height: 20px;
   border:1px black solid;
   width:100%;
}
```

check it in the snippet :

```js
$("body").on("click","#add-more",function(){ 
var html = $(".partPending").first().clone();
$(html).find(".change").html("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
$(".partPending").last().after(html);
});
 $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".partPending").remove();    
});
```

```css
div{
background : green;
}
.partPending {
   display:block;
   background:yellow;
   height: 20px;
   border:1px black solid;
  width:100%;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row p-20 partPending">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<x-forms.file allowedFileExtensions="png jpg jpeg" class="mr-0 mr-lg-2 mr-md-2" :fieldLabel="__('app.partImage')" fieldName="part_image"
                            fieldId="part_image" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<x-forms.file allowedFileExtensions=" mp4 avi " allowedFileSize=" 1mb" class="mr-0 mr-lg-2 mr-md-2" :fieldLabel="__('app.partVideo')" fieldName="part_video"
                            fieldId="part_video" />
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row px-lg-4 px-md-4 px-3 pb-3 pt-0 mb-3  mt-2">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <a class="f-15 f-w-500" href="javascript:;" id="add-more"><i
 class="icons icon-plus font-weight-bold mr-1"></i>@lang('app.addMore')</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have got it working by changing .add-more to #add-more it is adding more fields now but when i select image its not working

Comment: that's another question.

Comment: Please let me know how it will work

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you need when you say: "When I select an image it's not working". it needs more details, codes, and clarity to be understandable.